# Android Emulator OpenGL problems

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, android-emulator, opengl-es-2.0

Since I built a new computer I'm having problems running my current project on every emulator I could think of (e.g. Xamarin Android Player, Visual Studio Emulator, the Android SDK one ...). Every time I run the project on an emulator (it works on real devices just fine) the emulators screen is gray and only some text rendered by my "engine" appears.
(like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7AFos.png ). To develop my project I'm using Xamarin and OpenGL ES 2.

I've looked up all the logs from the different emulators and there are only a few differences when debugging on an emulator and a real device.

1. The log shows some crazy opengles errors

   - `I/OpenGLRenderer( 3523): Initialized EGL, version 1.4`
   - `W/EGL_emulation( 3523): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented`
   - `W/OpenGLRenderer( 3523): Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0x9c242f20, error=EGL_SUCCESS"`
2. There are quite many garbace collections (around one every second) whichs log look like this:

   - `D/Mono    ( 3523): GC_OLD_BRIDGE num-objects 1 num_hash_entries 1 sccs size 1 init 0.00ms df1 0.02ms sort 0.01ms dfs2 0.01ms setup-cb 0.01ms free-data 0.01ms links 0/0/0/0 dfs passes 0/0`
   - `D/Mono    ( 3523): GC_MINOR: (Nursery full) pause 0.51ms, total 0.73ms, bridge 0.01ms promoted 1216K major 1216K los 331K`

Here is my Android manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" package="com.tipfom.mapknight">
<uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" />
<uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="21" android:minSdkVersion="21" />
<application android:label="mapKnight" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:hardwareAccelerated="true"></application>´
```

I've allready tried to turn off Host GPU, increase the target and minSdkVersion of the Application, Download all AndroidSDK files till API 15 and install the Intel HAXM driver.

Comment: Assuming you are not running this within a VM itself (i.e. nested VMs) I would install one of the OpenGL test suites from Google Play onto your Emulator as a quick test as things missing from your code like  `glEnableClientState` will cause the emulators to fail but physical devices will work fine FYI: the Visual Studio one translates all `OpenGL-ES 2` calls to `DirectX` via `Angle` so if your pc/hardware supports `DirectX` it should just work...

Comment: FYI: The OpenGL ES `errors` you listed are not really errors and nothing you listed is an issue

Comment: At first I want to apologize if I stole your time. :) My error got neither caused by the emulator nor by opengl or xamarin. It simply was an globalization mistake that caused the float.Parse function to act different on my mobile devices and the emulator.